# Unable to require wysiwyg textbox MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor

I have it required on the back-end and the front-end and yet I can still submit the form...

**View Model**

```
[AllowHtml]
[Required]
public string ContentText { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(i => i.ContentText, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "form-control" }, { "rows", 4 }, { "id", "formContent" }, { "name", "ContentText" }, { "data-bind", "value:formContent" }, { "required", "required" } })
```

**Javascript**

```
CKEDITOR.replace('formContent');
```

Comment: which MVC are you speaking about?

Comment: the MVC I am using is C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with `ckeditor`, but in MVC the [`[Required]`](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) attribute is only part of the equation.

If you're using `EntityFramework`, calling `SaveChanges()` on the database would throw an exception if the model is invalid.

For submissions to the `controller`, you want to check `if (ModelState.IsValid) { //do something }` - this is false if there are any validation errors.
Note you can also check `if (ModelState.IsValidField("myField")) { //do something }` if you don't care about the whole model.

Whatever code is processing your submit needs to handle the invalid model. You can either do this in JS or C#.

Comment: I am using a ModelState.IsValid, it's not catching.

Comment: @BlowFish Can you update the question with that code then?

Comment: You gave me an idea, so I used some custom validation.  It triggered it great! Thanks so much!